# What is meaning of schema evolution for Parquet and Avro file format in Hive

Tags: hive

Can anyone explain meaning of schema evolution for parquet and Avro file format in Hive.

Answer (score 3):

Schema evolution is nothing but a term used for how to store the behaves when schema changes  . Users can start with a simple schema, and gradually add more columns to the schema as needed. In this way, users may end up with multiple Parquet/Avro files with different but mutually compatible schemas.

so lets say if you have one avro/parquet file and you want to change its schema, you can rewrite that file with a new schema inside. But what if you have terabytes of avro/parquet files and you want to change their schema? Will you rewrite all of the data, every time the schema changes?

Schema evolution allows you to update the schema used to write new data, while maintaining backwards compatibility with the schema(s) of your old data. Then you can read it all together, as if all of the data has one schema. Of course there are precise rules governing the changes allowed, to maintain compatibility. Those rules are listed under [Schema Resolution](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution).

Comment: great answer @Vin.. just one follow up question on how this schema evolution would be useful? Assume that some changes to the schema happens but no one notice that change, so no one knows about it? Also, AWS recommends to seperate data from schema so each layer can evolve independent of other but I don't understand what's the use of evolving one without have the other one? Suppose if schema is enhanced and there is no data, then its not useful and vice versa. I'm completely lost in this jargon. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74021971/schema-data-separation